# MacBook Pro doesn't wake up 4K external display connected via the displayport

Tags: mac, external-display, displayport, macbook-pro-retina, clamshell

I have a MacBook Pro Retina 15" Mid 2015 running Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) and I have a [Samsung U32D970Q](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/monitors/LU32D97KQSR/ZA) 4K external display that I would like to use in a closed clamshell mode through displayport to get 4K at 60Hz.

When I try to wake up MacBook my external display is not waking up. This happens randomly. In such case I have to disconnect the cable from the display port connection, open up the MacBook and reconnect it again. Sometimes only restarting MacBook solves the problem.

Previously I used my older MacBook in this setup but instead of a display port connector I used HDMI (but with only 30Hz, that is why I want to connect with displayport) and everything worked great.

Now, when I am connecting through displayport with new MacBook, I can’t find reason why is this happening. Is there any issue with displayport on new MacBook or Mac OS X?

Comment: I think this is an issue with the latest El-Capitan update. I have a MacPro and have same issues with display ports when the computer goes to sleep. I have to unplug and pick a different port to restore my monitor. After i use up the available thunderbolt / display port ports... I have to reboot or i will not have any monitor action. Highly irritating and wish i could go back one update in software.

Comment: Did you found a fix for this? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: No. I have just a workaround to connect both displayport and hdmi at the same time. Hdmi ensures that macbook will wake up and I am using display through displayport with 60 hz.